# SBT reloading dependencies each time

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

when I open sbt and start project it reloads dependecies like:

```
[info] Updating {file:/home/maciej/workspace/Job/test/}test-common...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.11;1.0.3 ...
[info] Updating {file:/home/maciej/workspace/Job/test/}Messaging...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
```

and when I open intellij it does the same, and after doing it in intellij if I start sbt project again it reloads again those dependecies..

Its really anoying.
Someone any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an experemental feature in 0.13.7 called [Cached Resolution](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cached-Resolution.html) that might help you.
Try to specify `sbt.version=0.13.7` in `project/build.properties`